# How to sketch this Domain of triple integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

i am having hard time **sketching** the domain of this :

> $$
> \ \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x^2}\int_0^y f(x,y,z){dz}{dy}{dx} $$

is there an easy way to do that ? i got like cylinder and planes and its hard to see the Volume domain

The question asking to sketch this " simple " domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You integrate with respect to $z$ first, keeping $x,y$ fixed. For any $(x,y), z$ ranges from $0\to y$. That means you're integrating below the plane $y=z$. Next you integrate with respect to $y$, keeping $x$ fixed. $y$ ranges from $0\to1-x^2$. This means you are integrating over the region below the parabola $y=1-x^2$, from $x=0\to1$, where it intersects the $x$ axis.

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1):

We have that

- in the $x$-$y$ plane the domain is the area between the parabola $y=1-x^2$ and positive axis
- coordinate $z$ varies between $z=0$ and $z=y$

therefore you can think to a cylinder with base $\{(x,y):x,y>0 \land y\le 1-x^2\}$ cutted by the plane $z=y$.

Comment: yes but can i draw that in the notebook is it possible ? because i cant draw that in 3d with 3 axis

Comment: @Mather You can draw it at first in the main planes $x-y (z=0)$, $x-y (z=1/2)$, $z-y (x=0)$, $z-x (y=0)$ and then you can try to draw it in 3D.

Comment: i have posted an image

Answer (score 1):

> is this sketch right ?  its like a cylinder cutted by z = y

[image]

Comment: Perfectly fine! Note that the z=y plane is at 45° with respect to x axis! Add that picture to your question!

Comment: @user376343 but $x$ varies form $0$ to $1$.

Comment: but the integral goes from x = 0 to x = 1 because  the third part is dx

Comment: yes so x<0 is not in the domain

Comment: Right @gimusi, thanks